# generalized notation for a product with permutations

Tags: summation, permutations

We define some coefficient for an example
\begin{split}
&\alpha_1= \frac{1}{(E_1+\eta)(E_2+\eta)(E_3+\eta)} \\
&\alpha_2=\frac{1 }{(E_1-\eta)(E_2-\eta)(E_3+\eta)}\\
&+\frac{1 }{(E_1-\eta)(E_2+\eta)(E_3-\eta)}\\
&+\frac{1 }{(E_1+\eta)(E_2-\eta)(E_3-\eta)}\\
&\alpha_3= \frac{1}{(E_1-\eta)(E_2+\eta)(E_3+\eta)}\\
&+\frac{1}{(E_1+\eta)(E_2-\eta)(E_3+\eta)}\\
&+\frac{1}{(E_1+\eta)(E_2+\eta)(E_3-\eta)}\\
&\alpha_4= \frac{1}{(E_1-\eta)(E_2-\eta)E_3-\eta)}
\end{split}

What is a general formula to generate this?

Answer (score 1):

Here we have the following situation:

- There are four variables $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$.
- Each variable $\alpha_k, 1\leq k\leq 4$ is a sum with $\binom{3}{k-1}$ summands.
- Each summand of $\alpha_k, 1\leq k\leq 4$ has three factors,  $\binom{3}{k-1}$ with a minus sign and $3-\binom{3}{k-1}$ with a plus sign.

We can therefore use the three element index set $[3]:=\{1,2,3\}$ and we can write
\begin{align*}
a_k=\sum_{{S\subseteq [3]}\atop {|S|=k-1}}\prod_{s\in S}\frac{1}{E_s-\eta}
\prod_{s\in [3]\setminus S}\frac{1}{E_s+\eta}\qquad\qquad 1\leq k\leq 4
\end{align*}

> In general we  obtain using the notation $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\alpha_{k}=\sum_{{S\subseteq [n]}\atop {|S|=k-1}}\prod_{s\in S}\frac{1}{E_s-\eta}
> \prod_{s\in [n]\setminus S}\frac{1}{E_s+\eta}\qquad\qquad 1\leq k\leq n}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @sultana: You're welcome. :-)